# Syntax error using ampersand (bitwise and) in GDB user defined command

Tags: gdb

I am attempting to create a GDB user-defined command.

```
def decodecs
  if $argc == 1
    set $lowaddr=(short*)($arg0)
    x /h $lowaddr
    # The line below generates the error
    set $lowaddr=$lowaddr & (short)0xfff8
    x /h $lowaddr
    set $lowaddr=$lowaddr >> (short)3
    set $highaddr = (short*)($arg0+2)
    x /h $highaddr
  end
```

The error reported by GDB is:

```
Argument to arithmetic operation not a number or boolean
```

I have set the language to c. `set language c`

The error message is reported between the first and second 'x ...' outputs.

When I type the commands at the GDB prompt I do not get an error and the operation works as expected.

I am debugging a legacy program. It does not have GDB compatible debug symbols.

I am using a GDB cross for M68k, v4.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
set $lowaddr=(short*)($arg0)
```

creates a GDB convenience variable of type `short*`. GDB will refuse bitwise operations on anything that is not a number, as can be trivially seen from trying:

```
(gdb) set $foo = (short*)0x1234
(gdb) p $foo
$1 = (short *) 0x1234
(gdb) p $foo & 0xff
Argument to arithmetic operation not a number or boolean.
```

So perform your operations on *integers*, and cast to pointer only when necessary. In your snippet you only use the pointer to `x/h`, which doesn't need a pointer *at all*.